# Need to show all items, one item in a row

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView that is populated from Firebase Realtime Database. It should work as whatsapp.

I have created a collectionView cell to show the messages in a label.

I have set the collectionView scroll direction to vertical.

I have set the cell height to 40, and here you have the method sizeForItemAt:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {


    return CGSize(width:collectionView.frame.size.width, height:40)

   }
```

The items are shown, but not at full width and not one item per row.

Here you have a screenshot:
[image]

What do I need to change to get each item in a row?

Comment: Are you setting the delegate and datasource properly.

Comment: Btw why not use `UITableView`? UITableView handles these scenarios much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the method is not getting called here. You need to set the `delegate` of `collectionView` to the `class`. Add this to `viewDidLoad`.

```
collectionView.delegate = self
```

Suggested Approach: My suggested approach for your requirement is to use `UITableView`. All the cells extend the entire width of the `UITableView`. You just need to provide the height of the cell by this method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    40
}
```

Comment: I have set both delegates as follows: chatCV.delegate = self.                                      
  chatCV.dataSource = self

Comment: but same result

Comment: Check if the method is getting called using a breakpoint or print statement.

Comment: it is called once per item

Comment: So, delegate is proper, turns out issue could be with `collectionView.frame.size.width` try printing this in the method.

Comment: What should I print?

Comment: Try printing `collectionView.frame.size.width`. find the reason why the width is not the width of super-view. Add the code where you're setting frame or providing constraints.

Comment: I can try using a tableview, if you mean it would be easier

Comment: Yes, it's much easier and the suggested approach for your purpose. Check my update to this answer.